# Maven systemPath is not added to runtime classpath

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I need to add JDK's tools.jar as a project dependency.

Setting it as a normal dependency is not working, because when installing it to the Maven repository, it adds a version number to the jar file. Thereafter, when I need something that needs tools.jar to be in the classpath, it fails.

Using the system scope and setting the path to the jar using < systemPath > should solve the problem. However, although in tests the jar is added to the classpath, at runtime it is not.

Is there a way around this?

Btw, I've added < useManifestOnlyJar >false< /useManifestOnlyJar > to the surefireplugin so that I can see every file in the classpath.

Comment: how do you run the application in runtime ? is it war, executable jar, or anything else ? is there a launching script ? In other words, how do you use runtime classpath prepared by Maven ?

Answer (score 3):

Is Maven running in a JDK?

Find out what version of Java it's running,

> mvn -ver

Set your JAVA_HOME env variable to point to a JDK.

Comment: +1: If you're running Maven under a JRE, tools.jar will not be in the runtime classpath.

Comment: Even if you're running under a JDK, the property java.home will still be set to the jre - see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide

Answer (score 1):

if it is not included in your JDK, use system scope, see the [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency)

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>default-tools.jar</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>java.vendor</name>
        <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```